# issue when insert text to db using js

Tags: php, javascript, variables, submit

i try to submit text to db, but in the db field not inserted any text.

can you analyze where my false?

i try like this.

Thanks for your help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function() {
        var namaklasifier = document.getElementByName("tfklasifier").value;
        var inputpos= document.getElementByName("tacaripos").value;
        var inputnet = document.getElementByName("tacarinet").value;
        var inputneg = document.getElementByName("tacarineg").value;    
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
        $('#resultcoba').html(data);}
    })
        return false;
  });
    })
</script>    
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="proses.php">
<td align="center" valign="top" style="width:420px"><textarea style="width:420px" name="tacaripos" rows="4" cols="70"><?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['tacaripos']);?></textarea></td>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="width:420px"><textarea style="width:420px" name="tacarinet" rows="4" cols="70"><?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['tacarinet']);?></textarea></td>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="width:420px"><textarea style="width:420px" name="tacarineg" rows="4" cols="70"><?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['tacarineg']);?></textarea></td>
</tr>
<td align="center"><input type="submit" name="btklasifier" id="btklasifier" value="Buat" /></td></form>
```

**proses.php**

```
    <?php    
       $namaklasifier=$_POST['namaklasifier'];
$jadipos=$_POST['inputpos'];
$jadinet=$_POST['inputnet'];
$jadineg=$_POST['inputneg'];

$link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","skripsi");
mysqli_select_db($link,"skripsi");
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO namaklasifier(username,datapos,datanet,dataneg,user) VALUES('$namaklasifier','$jadipos','$jadinet','$jadineg','{$_SESSION['username']}')"); ?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: as a sidenote, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and not very secure. You should be using mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the GET data under the variable names you have declared here:

```
var namaklasifier = document.getElementByName("tfklasifier").value;
var inputpos= document.getElementByName("tacaripos").value;
var inputnet = document.getElementByName("tacarinet").value;
var inputneg = document.getElementByName("tacarineg").value;
```

Yet you are sending them using `$(this).serialize()` which means you must access the GET variables using the input name as this is what serialize does (creates an object from the form elements using their names). e.g.

```
$jadipos=$_POST['tacaripos'];
$jadinet=$_POST['tacarinet'];
$jadineg=$_POST['tacarineg'];
```

Also you need to change `$_GET` to `$_POST` as that is the method you are using.

Comment: thanks, but my field of db no inserted any text, just insert blank

Comment: @user2413763 Edited answer now uses POST method. Should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

In `proses.php`, change the `$_GET` into `$_POST`.

Since you are using `POST` method to submit data, naturally, you have to use the `$_POST` variables.

Answer (score 1):

They are **POST** values not the **GET** ones

```
$jadipos=$_POST['inputpos'];
$jadinet=$_POST['inputnet'];
$jadineg=$_POST['inputneg'];
```

And try to use mysqli_* functions or PDO statements,instead of mysql_* functions due to they are deprecated

EDIT:also try like

```
var namaklasifier = document.getElementByName("tfklasifier").value;
    var inputpos= document.getElementByName("tacaripos").value;
    var inputnet = document.getElementByName("tacarinet").value;
    var inputneg = document.getElementByName("tacarineg").value;    
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:  $(this).attr('action'),
      data: {inputpos:inputpos,inputnet:inputnet,inputneg:inputneg},
      success: function(data) {
         $('#resultcoba').html(data);}
     })
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: Hi @Gautama, i have update my proses.php but still blank in db.

Comment: i just try the code, but still blank in db. this is why from begin i have desperated. :(